# Date input in form field is not submitted

Tags: javascript, forms, date

I have some code that successfully inputs a variety of values into a form on a webpage and I can see that the data is put into the correct fields in the correct format. When I submit the form using the 'OK' button on the screen, or code, the process completes but the Date data carried through is the current date, despite the fact that I can see a different date displayed in the field. I can cut and paste data into the field from e.g., Notepad and it works fine.

So, in short, although I can see the correct Date date on screen it does not submit when supplied by the script.

Here is the html for relevant part of the form with what I think is relevant code flanking it:

```
    <iframe id="mainPanel_iframe" name="mainPanel_iframe" class="mochaIframe" src="https://portal.starleaf.com/pbx/node-1.live.pr.starleaf.com/portal/#page=addUserConference&amp;">

#document
                <div> class="mainTableContainer">
                    <form action="#" method="get">
                        <div class="formRow">
                            <div class="fieldBlock calendarBlock">
                                <input type="date" id="editConference_startNative" class="native_date has_native">
                                <input type="text" id="editConference_start" class="sl_date has_native" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                                <input type="text" id="editConference_startTime" placeholder="Time" class="ui-timepicker-input" autocomplete="off">
                                <div id="start-date-picker"><div class="pika-single is-hidden is-bound" style="position: static; left: auto; top: auto;"></div></div>
                                <div id="start-time-picker"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>  

                <div class="buttons">
                    <input type="button" id="editConference_ok" value="OK">
                </div>
    </iframe>
```

Here is the Javascript that I have been using. I have been testing it out using the Chrome F12 Console and working inside the iframe. It automates the filling out of the form and submits it.  The line with StDate (`id="editConference_start"`) does not work but the next line with StTime (`id="editConference_startTime"`) does pull through after 'clicking'.  Both are `type="text"`.

\Loading the data into the fields

```
var StDate = "06/05/2020";
document.getElementById('editConference_start').value = StDate;

var StTime = "16:20";
document.getElementById('editConference_startTime').value = StTime;
```

\ Click 'OK'

```
document.getElementById("editConference_ok").click();
```

Things tried:

1) Using the code below to enter data via the id ="editConference_startNative" element. It does not seem to work but I am not sure if my code makes any sense or if this something worth pursing:

```
var StDate = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
StDate.value = '2020-05-05';
document.getElementById('editConference_startNative').value = StDate;
```

2) Creating a var with a date type for use with the Native version of the input

```
var StDate = new Date("05/05/2020");
document.getElementById('editConference_startNative').value = StDate;
```

I think the output is in the wrong form to be used but can't figure out how to shorten it in the right format. Perhaps this is not the right approach.

3) Removing the final click code then waiting for a few seconds and them adding the Click line into the Console and executing but this did not work.  I presume it is not a question of a delay. I also tried this code before the click code for a delay but I am not sure if it is valid:

```
setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);
document.getElementById("editConference_ok").click();
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: maybe `document.getElementById('editConference_startNative').value = new Date(StDate);`

Comment: HI ariel, thanks.  The  line you suggested does not enter any data into the 'Native' field (which is usually display: none, but i looked).  I wondered if the product of the new Date(StDate) operation is in the right format.  I think it is like this for 05/06/2020:  Wed May 06 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time).  Do you know how to covert this back to 05/06/2020.  Seems a bit round the houses...

Comment: i'd say then, just use string and convert it on the server side